# Change color for the next line I'm drawing, without closing the path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm making kind of a paint program.

I'm trying to make buttons of different colors that serves the purpose of change the color of the next path the user is drawing.

I found this question, which has the same problem ([HTML5 Canvas changes colors of all lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251507/html5-canvas-changes-colors-of-all-lines)), but its answer has a solution that isn't the result I'm looking for (I don't want to close the figure with `closePath()`, I want to leave incomplete paths)

Is there a way to do it without being forced to close the figure?

### [Here's my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/z9NQD/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `beginPath()`, when you start a new line

```js
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    down = true;
    ctx.beginPath();
}).mouseup(function() {
    down = false;  
});
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9NQD/9/)